# textbox validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the same code for creating many text boxes. Now for validation purpose is there a way to find the datatype of a field in front end. for example

```
$('textarea').change(function() {
    if (isNaN(this.value)) {
        alert("Field cannot accept spaces, special characters");
    }
});
```

This applies for all textboxes which are non numeric. Any help or suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the datatype when creating the element, you can set that information on the element by either creating a custom attribute like 'data_type="numeric"' or by adding a data object to the element: $('textarea').data('type', numeric).

Then, you can create a generic onchange

```
$('textarea').change(function(){
    if($(this).data('type') == 'numeric'){
        if(isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val() ))){
        ....
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This project](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) should fulfill all your needs in terms of forms validations

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jquery validation? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation